# Google Friend Connect ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, google-friend-connect

I am using the JS APIS for Google Friend Connect in my ASP.NET app. I am not able to run the application at all. If any body could please let me know how to get the FriendList and show it in ASP.NET page that will be great help.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Here is the step by step procedure to integrate asp.net membership with google friend connect:
http://am22tech.com/s/22/Blogs/post/2010/03/14/Integrate-Google-friend-connect-(GFC)-with-existing-aspnet-membership.aspx

Once you are done with the integration, you will be able to see the friend list and sign in button for GFC.